# Squared norm of linear system proportional to Multivariate Gaussian log-density?

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, density-function, multivariate-normal-distribution

I am reading https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/140964023, and I got confused by this part:

[image]

In the above, it is assumed that $m \geq n$.
If $m = n$, I can see how the above works.
$|| J \theta - y||^2 = (J \theta - y)^\top (J \theta - y)$, denoting with $\top$ transposition, and with $J$ full (column) rank we can factor $(J \theta - y) = J(\theta - J^{-1}y)$ which gives the stated result after simple manipulations.

If $m > n$ and $J$ is full column rank, the pseudo-inverse $J^\dagger = (J^\top J)^{-1}J^\top$ satisfies $J^\dagger J = I$, for the identity matrix $I$.
But we cannot use $J^\dagger$ in place of $J^{-1}$ to factorize, as we need the right inverse, not the left one.
This would be the case of $m < n$ and a full row rank $J$, using the pseudo-inverse $J^{\dagger\dagger} = J^\top(J J^\top)^{-1}$.

I am inclined to think that the mistake is mine, and that I am missing something obvious.
Is it the case that, with the stated assumptions ($J$ is a full column rank matrix with size $m \times n$, $m \geq n$), we obtain a multivariate Gaussian distribution with mean vector and covariance matrix stated above?

Comment: "Full column rank" is equivalent to a nonzero determinant of the $n\times n$ matrix $J^\prime J.$  It's unclear what role any pseudo-inverses would play here or why the value of $m$ would even be relevant.  To what "mistake" are you referring, then?

Comment: @whuber the claim in the paper is that $p(\theta|y)$ is Gaussian with stated mean and covariance. That is to say $||J\theta -y||^2 = (\theta - \mu)^\top \Sigma^{-1}(\theta - \mu)$ for $\Sigma = (J^\top J)^{-1}$ and $\mu = (J^\top J)^{-1}J^\top y$. However, the term independent of $\theta$ in $||J\theta -y||^2$ is $y^\top y$, while the same for $(\theta - \mu)^\top \Sigma^{-1}(\theta - \mu)$ is $y^\top J (J^\top J)^{-1}J^\top y$, which doesn't simplify, so the equality doesn't hold. By mistake, I mean my failure in understanding / proving the stated results.

Comment: That logic is rather obscure.  The two conclusions about how the mean and covariance are functions of $J$ and $y$ can be verified simply by inspection, a process known as [completing the square](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=complet*+square)

Comment: That logic would be correct where the quoted density a density. I posted my self-answer, thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that the right hand side of the reported equation does not define a valid density when $m > n$, as the normalizing constant is not correct.
In particular it is not evaluate to the density of a multivariate Gaussian, which can be verified numerically.

What is true, is that an $n$-dimensional random variable with density $p(\theta|y)$ proportional to

$$
\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}||J\theta - y||^2\right\}
$$

is distributed according to a multivariate Gaussian distribution, with the mean and covariance as stated, the only requirement being that $J^\top J$ is invertible.
This can be checked, as suggested in the comments, by completing the square.

---

Update: Mathematica code illustrating the issue.

code:

```
J = {{1, -2},{-3, 1/2}};
y = {1/2, 2};
μ = Inverse[Transpose[J].J].Transpose[J].y;
Σ = Inverse[Transpose[J].J];
x = {-1, 1};

Dimensions[J]
(J.x - y).(J.x - y)
(x - μ).Inverse[Σ].(x - μ)
1 / (Sqrt[(2 π)^n Det[Σ]]) * Exp[-1/2 (x - μ).Inverse[Σ].(x - μ)]
1 / (Sqrt[(2 π)^n Det[Σ]]) * Exp[-1/2 (J.x - y).(J.x - y)]
```

result:
[image]

code:

```
J = {{1}, {-3}};
y = {1/2, 2};
μ = Inverse[Transpose[J].J].Transpose[J].y;
Σ = Inverse[Transpose[J].J];
x = {-1};

Dimensions[J]
(J.x - y).(J.x - y)
(x - μ).Inverse[Σ].(x - μ)
1 / (Sqrt[(2 π)^n Det[Σ]]) * Exp[-1/2 (x - μ).Inverse[Σ].(x - μ)]
1 / (Sqrt[(2 π)^n Det[Σ]]) * Exp[-1/2 (J.x - y).(J.x - y)]
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific about how the normalizing constant is incorrect? I detect a typographical error where "$m$" is used in place of "$n,$" but otherwise it looks okay.

Comment: $\theta$ is $n$-dimensional, as $J$ is $m \times n$ and we have $J \theta$. If the quoted formula were the density of a multivariate Gaussian as stated, necessarily the terms inside the $\exp$ would need to match $(\theta - \mu)^\top \Sigma^{-1} (\theta - \mu)$ for the stated $\mu,\Sigma$. Expanding, this cannot be the case (this is my previous comment). I added Mathematica code for confirmation.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible because it doesn't define `n` -- and `n` appears to be an even number in the second example where it should equal $1.$

Comment: `Dimensions[J]` gives `{m, n}`. In the code `x` is $\theta$.

Comment: Yes, but you never assign the result of `Dimensions` to any variable!  You would be better off actually doing the algebra rather than relying on code: it brings better understanding.